# I'm trying to pass a variable to another script as an argument but it isnt working

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I change the content file and styleFile vars for just the file path, it works fine. So I know that the content file is there and that it can find it.

I must be passing a variable incorrectly to the other python script. I've been trying but I can't google myself out of this one at the moment.

```
import os

listStyles = ['/content/neural-style-tf/styles/1.png']
listContent = ['/content/neural-style-tf/image_input/00078.png']

i = 0

for imageName in listStyles:
  stylefile = imageName
  contentfile = listContent[i]
  i = i + 1

  print (stylefile)
  
  print (contentfile)

  print ('')
  
  !python neural_style.py --content_img contentfile --style_imgs stylefile
```

Output:

```
/content/neural-style-tf/styles/1.png
/content/neural-style-tf/image_input/00078.png

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "neural_style.py", line 889, in <module>
    main()
  File "neural_style.py", line 886, in main
    else: render_single_image()
  File "neural_style.py", line 849, in render_single_image
    content_img = get_content_image(args.content_img)
  File "neural_style.py", line 715, in get_content_image
    check_image(img, path)
  File "neural_style.py", line 552, in check_image
    raise OSError(errno.ENOENT, "No such file", path)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file: './image_input/contentfile'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just dumb and need to not just brute force a language when I need it and learn it beforehand.

If anyone else comes across this you need to put a $ in front of the variable to let python know you're passing a var instead of a string.